# How to add search parameter to the URL using AngularJS UI Router .go()?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is there a way to add a search parameter to the URL when using UI-Router's `$state.go()`? I would like to use a defined state with additional info in the URL instead of defining a new route with the same configuration.

I have a simple view defined:

```
.when('page-with-form', {
    template: 'views/page-with-form.html',
    url: '/page-with-form'
})
```

I want the route to work as normal when someone navigates to `/page-with-form` but when I have something else in the application that would redirect the user to that route with some additional information `/page-with-form?error=true` something like this perhaps:

```
$state.go('page-with-form', '?error=true');
```

Comment: The additional information can be passed as second parameter to go as an object hash `{}`, you can then get it later using `$stateParams`. See docs https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#wiki-stategoto--toparams--options

Comment: I know about that, the problem I was trying to solve was not making them state parameters but search elements of the URI. So, instead of `page-with-form/error/true` I want `page-with-form?error=true`. Does that make sense.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This would be solution with `ui-router` - [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/aifLujW2Lxky8pygFdEE?p=preview)

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('MyState', {
      url: '/page-with-form?error',
      templateUrl: 'view.page-with-form.html',
      controller: 'MyCtrl',
    })
```

The navigation to this state could be like this:

```
  // href
  <a href="#/page-with-form">
  <a href="#/page-with-form?error=true">
  <a href="#/page-with-form?error=false">

  //ui-sref
  <a ui-sref="MyState({error:null})">
  <a ui-sref="MyState({error:true})">
  <a ui-sref="MyState({error:false})">

  // state.go() - in fact very similar to ui-sref directive
  $state.go('MyState', {error: null})
  $state.go('MyState', {error: true})
  $state.go('MyState', {error:false})
```

The documentation to url params:

- [Query Parameters](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#query-parameters) *(small cite)*

> You can also specify parameters as query parameters, following a '?':

```
url: "/contacts?myParam"
// will match to url of "/contacts?myParam=value"
```

Test it in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/aifLujW2Lxky8pygFdEE?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks. That seems like exactly what I was looking for. I think that I eventually found it in what I was working on but didn't come back here to post the answer. So thank you for sharing with everyone.

Comment: Great to see that! Enjoy amazing `ui-router` lib ;)

Answer (score 6):

As I understand, you're looking for **optional** query parameters. Fortunately, query parameters are optional by default. Just try: `url: '/page-with-form?error'`

```
.when('page-with-form', {
    template: 'views/page-with-form.html',
    url: '/page-with-form?error'
});
```

And use `$state.go('page-with-form', {error:true});`